# Explanation of Explode function with FILTER_SANITIZE_URL

Tags: php, url

I have some problem with Explode function.

```
public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])){
          $tmp = filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
          return $url = explode('/', $tmp);
        }
    }
```

If i'm using this this isn't working but if i do this

```
public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])){
          //$tmp = filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
          return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
```

This works fine can anyone explain what is the problem if I'm using one more variable in Explode function

Comment: your both code works for me:-  https://eval.in/619838  (i have changed some parts). So based on that i can say either calling those function part is not correct or you missed something which is not shown here

Comment: okay ill check it again thanks

Comment: I think you have those function inside class. What i showed you is procedural approach. So may be difference happen. But my code is that much easy, that you can change your code accordingly.

Comment: u know that function parse_url() exists in php?

Comment: "this isn't working" - your question misses the input and the output and you don't write what exactly qualifies as not working with that input and output. Most likely this is the reason why this is not answered so far, it's incomplete for Q&A.